# Which cameras would win in a duel?

Tags: camera-settings, camera-recommendation

Real question: Looking for a consumer camera that can go from off to snapped a photo very very fast.

(Camera dual question: cameras are in off position. which would be the fastest, turning it on and snapping a photo. (Or from sleep state)

Comment: Maybe is wise to mention the camera models :)

Comment: not familiar with any . wanted to hear from some knowledgeable ppl

Comment: Even with identical models, the selected settings for each could make a very significant difference.

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve here? Give us a bit more detail and we can help a lot more.

Comment: Edited question. But does it really have to be trying to solve a problem. What about asking for knowledge's sake?

Answer (score 6):

Who wins a real rootin' tootin' shoot-em-up dual? The guy with the gun that has the shortest lag time between the time the trigger is pulled and the firing pin strikes the primer? Or the guy that is the fastest gunslinger no matter what is in his holster? If both contestants are that close to the same speed, the bullets are going to pass each other between the two duelers anyway, and no one wins.

The guy who gets the shot (photo, that is) is not always the one with the fastest camera. It is almost always the photographer that was [best prepared](http://www.news.com.au/sport/sports-life/the-story-behind-the-greatest-photograph-in-sports-history/news-story/781e32670a84a2bfadcfb494eb0a924d) *before* the decisive moment happened. Neil Leifer spent several hours before the match placing his strobes in the rafters of the arena for the Ali-Liston fight. He did it so he could use slow color slide film for *one shot*.

[image: http://dujye7n3e5wjl.cloudfront.net/photographs/1080-tall/time-100-influential-photos-neil-leifer-muhammad-ali-vs-sonny-liston-56.jpg]

The fuller story from [Sports Illustrated](https://www.si.com/boxing/video/2016/11/16/100-photographs-muhammad-ali-vs-sonny-liston) including interview excerpts from Leifer.

Comment: Nicely explained.

Comment: A nice story, a nice shot, and a nice lesson :)

Comment: What about the machine gunner - the JPEG shooting dude with the Sony APS-C or D500 and a good memory card going all out CH at the first hint of possible action?

Comment: @rackandboneman Those are the 1965 equivalent of those guys helplessly looking at Ali's backside, including Leifer's boss who got first pick at which side of the ring he would shoot from and can be seen through Ali's legs. They were shooting "fast" monochrome film.

Comment: Sadly, it seems to linked article is no longer available at SI.com, at least not directly at the link.